# Interesting std::copy from std::vector to std::string behavior

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdstring

I was messing around with `ostream_iterator` and realized that when specifying a delimiter, it outputs one too many. So instead I went with `ostringstream` so I could modify the string before outputting it. But then I realized I should just use a `string` directly. The one issue is however, with the following code:

**code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 42);

    std::string s(" ", v.size());
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), s.begin());
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the output is:

**output:**

```
**********
```

However with

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 42);

std::ostream_iterator<int> osi(oss);

std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), osi);

std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;
```

The output is

**output**

```
 42424242424242424242
```

Obviously it's converting the number to its ASCII representation. Does it simply do a `char cast`, or is it a side-effect of the complicated internals of the STL? Regardless, how would I change it to output numbers instead of asteriks?

Comment: change it to obtain what?

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: `int` and `char` are different things, you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just copying the number 42 from `int` to whatever character type is used in the underlying representation of your string (probably `char`), truncating any bits that won't fit (in your case, no truncation needed). In then stores this `char` type into each element of the string. When the string is printed it simply prints the ASCII (or whatever your architecture's character set is) representation of 42.

If you want to print the number 42 as the string `42` on your terminal, you need to use formatted output to do the display. Your `ostream_iterator` approach seems to be a reasonable approach here.